# Possible memory leak in cordova commandDelegate's evalJs function?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, memory-leaks

I am observing a possible memory leak in my ios phonegap application. In the code, I narrowed it down to the line where cordova calls evalJs function like below:

```
NSString* someString = @"some_event_on_JS_Side";
-(void) updateUI {
  for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
     [self.commandDelegate evalJs:someString];
}
```

updateUI function is called 15 times a second. Of course, normally I don't have the for loop and the consumed memory shown in XCode keeps rising like 0.1Mb per second.

But suspicious of a memory leak, I inserted a for loop there and A-ha, there was the leak! I don't see any garbage collection performed by the ARC, and the memory consumption rises to 1Gb+ with the for loop and keeps rising.

Is this a known issue? What can I do to solve this problem?

I know the ARC is running because normally I had "someString" allocated in "updateUI" and if I just loop the allocation (not the evalJs) the memory consumption rises until 250Mb, and increases no more.

Lastly, the event is always consumed on the JS side, so the problem shouldn't be related to that.

Comment: If you put an `@autoreleasepool` inside your `for` loop, does the leak go away?

Comment: @IanMacDonald  Unfortunately no, it still keeps rising (600Mb and increasing)

Comment: i have similar example but same result.